# Why did the anaconda installer not install conda-develop

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, conda

Im trying to get an existing codebase up and running and after installing anaconda with the .sh file from https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux I noticed in ~/anaconda3/bin the only conda files available are conda, conda-env and conda-server

We have another machine with conda 4.2.15 and the files are there
My machine with conda 4.3.8 does not have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conda-develop` is part of a separate package now. You can install it with:

`conda install conda-build`